# Deep find property type in a class instance

Tags: .net, reflection, system.reflection

I have a method which parses the xml and creates an object of a specified type from that xml.
This is all done using generics so as to have a common method for all types.

My issue is that I want to search for a property in various classes using its type name (not by the name).
Lets say property has a type "type1" then some of the class definition is declared below:

```
class foo1
{
  type1 prop1{get;set;}
}

class foo2
{
  foo1 prop2{get;set;}
}

class foo3:foo2
{
  type2 prop3{get;set;}
}
```

For all the above declared classes, if I create objects then I want to access `type1` typed properties for each instance of the above said classes i.e. I should be able to get value of property declared as `type1` from objects of `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3` classes. I really want a generic way to do this as the classes may increase.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to *almost* do this.  What is missing is that using reflection, BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy does not return private methods of parent classes.  Marking these types as protected or public will resolve this.  (You could also manually traverse base classes to read private members.)

If you wanted to find all types in an assembly that declare a property of a given type, you could write a method like:

```
// using System.Reflection

public IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithPropertyOfType(Assembly a, Type t)
{
    BindingFlags propertyBindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public 
                                       | BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                       | BindingFlags.Instance 
                                       | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;

    // a property is kept if it is assignable from the type
    // parameter passed in            
    MemberFilter mf = (pi, crit)=>
          (pi as PropertyInfo)
          .PropertyType
          .IsAssignableFrom(t);

    // a class is kept if it contains at least one property that
    // passes the property filter.  All public and nonpublic properties of
    // the class, and public and protected properties of the base class,
    // are considered
    Func<Type, bool> ClassFilter = 
        c=>c.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Property, propertyBindingFlags, mf, null)
            .FirstOrDefault() != null;

    // return all classes in the assembly that match ClassFilter
    return
        a.GetTypes()
        .Where(c=>c.IsClass)
        .Where(ClassFilter);
}
```

To find classes in the executing assembly that define or inherit a property of type `type1`, you might call:

```
    var v = GetTypesWithPropertyOfType(
           Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
           typeof(type1));

    foreach (var n in v) Console.WriteLine(n.FullName);
```

This prints out foo1.  If your code defining the foo classes is revised to (a) make `foo1.prop1` public or protected, and (b) make `foo2` inherit from `foo1`, then the above code prints:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
```

as expected.

Comment: How can I modify the above method to get the property value which are of type "type1".? Please let me know. My intent is to get the values of an instance of any class.

Comment: Hey I got another solution (non reflection approach) as I think it is too much to invest the effort. But thanks for the help.